# Trying to create a method to check for balanced strings

Tags: java, stack

Here is my code for the method, does not give me errors but is not working when calling it out, any help would be appreciated thanks:

```java
static boolean isBalanced(String expr) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for (char ch : expr.toCharArray()) {

        if (ch == '{' || ch == '(' || ch == '[') {
            stack.push(expr);
        } else {
            if (expr.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            char latestOpenedPar = (char) stack.pop();

            if (latestOpenedPar == '{' && ch != '}') {
                return false;
            } else if (latestOpenedPar == '(' && ch != ')') {
                return false;
            } else if (latestOpenedPar == '[' && ch != ']') {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Every developer should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

If the string is `"(abc)"` you are going to push the `(` and then pop it four times, once for each of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `)`, which of course will not work. Also `expr.isEmpty()` will never return true inside the loop because if it were empty, `expr.toCharArray()` would have returned a zero-length array and the loop would execute zero times. Use [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#peek()) to look at the top of the stack without removing it.

Also, your stack should be declared as:

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
```

in which case you would not need to cast the value returned by `pop()` or `peek()`; it would be automatically unboxed from a `Character` to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the question but I guess you want to understand if the different brackets are "consistent".

1. `if (expr.isEmpty()) {return false;}` this is useless because if the condition were true it would never enter the for loop
2. `if (ch == '{' || ch == '(' || ch == '[') {stack.push(expr);}`  here you put in the stack the entire string taken as input but after you comparing `stack.pop()` with the various brackets, so the right statement can be `stack.push(ch);`
3. You do `stack.pop()` without checking that the stack has at least one element